# Test field looses focus after I input a character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a list of input fields with reorder-able functionality , but the issues is the textfield looses focus on every onChange hit.
I am using [react-draggable-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable-list) package.

I looked into related questions and tried giving keys to all the component but it still doesn't work.

Find my code base [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reorderable-input-iz8no).

Below is the Multi-Input field for my form.

```
import { Box, Button, IconButton, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import DragIcon from "@material-ui/icons/OpenWith";
import ReorderableList from "./ReorderableList";
import { uniqueId } from "lodash";

import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
export interface ReorderableTierFieldProps {}
const ReorderableTierField: FC<ReorderableTierFieldProps> = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState<{ name: string; id: string }[]>([
    { name: "Input", id: uniqueId() }
  ]);

  const handleRemove = (itemIndex: number) => {
    let items = [...values];
    items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    setValues([...items]);
  };
  const renderAssetItem = (
    item: any,
    dragHandleProps: any = {},
    dragged?: boolean
  ) => {
    return (
      <Box display="flex" mb={2}>
        <TextField
          key={`text`}
          value={values[item.itemIndex].name || ""}
          onChange={(v) => {
            let items = [...values];
            items[item.itemIndex].name = v.target.value;
            setValues([...items]);
          }}
        />
        <IconButton size="small" onClick={() => handleRemove(item.itemIndex)}>
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <div id="drag" className="drag" {...dragHandleProps}>
          <DragIcon />
        </div>
      </Box>
    );
  };
  const onReorder = (newList: any[]) => {
    setValues([...newList]);
  };
  const onAdd = () => {
    setValues((v) => [...v, { id: uniqueId(), name: "" }]);
    //formikProps.setFieldValue('partnerTiers', [...values, { id: uniqueId() }])
  };
  return (
    <Box width={"100%"} key="gamma">
      <ReorderableList<{ id: string; name: string }>
        key="beta"
        list={values.map((ite, index) => ({ ...ite, itemIndex: index }))}
        handleUpdateListOrder={onReorder}
        renderItem={renderAssetItem}
      />
      <Button size="small" onClick={onAdd}>
        {"Add tier"}
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default ReorderableTierField;
```

Below is Reorderable List component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DraggableList, { TemplateProps } from "react-draggable-list";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

interface IProps<T = any> {
  list: T[];
  handleUpdateListOrder: (
    nexList: T[],
    movedItem: T,
    oldIndex: number,
    newIndex: number
  ) => void;
  renderItem: (
    item: T,
    dragHandleProps: any,
    dragged: boolean
  ) => React.ReactElement;
}

function ReorderableList<T extends any>(props: IProps<T & { id: string }>) {
  const { list } = props;
  class MyRender extends Component<TemplateProps<T & { id: string }, unknown>> {
    render() {
      let { item, itemSelected, dragHandleProps } = this.props;
      const dragged = itemSelected !== 0;
      return props.renderItem(item, dragHandleProps, dragged);
    }
  }
  return (
    <Box key="list_container">
      <DraggableList
        key="display"
        list={list || []}
        itemKey={(ite) => ite.id}
        template={MyRender as any}
        onMoveEnd={(nexList, movedItem, oldIndex, newIndex) =>
          props.handleUpdateListOrder(
            [...nexList],
            movedItem,
            oldIndex,
            newIndex
          )
        }
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default ReorderableList;
```

Answer (score 2):

add autoFocus property to TextField

```
<TextField
          id={item.itemIndex}
          autoFocus={currentItem === item.itemIndex}
          value={values[item.itemIndex].name || ""}
          onChange={(v) => {
            let items = [...values];
            items[item.itemIndex].name = v.target.value;
            setCurrentItem(item.itemIndex);
            setValues([...items]);
          }}
        />
```

I did modification to your code please check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reorderable-input-forked-zmwqn?file=/src/MyInput.tsx:878-1174)

Comment: That solution won't work since you will always autofocus the last element in the list, if you add more input fields you will see that your solution autofocuses the last input field in the list.

Comment: I added some changes now it works, please take a look

Comment: Im not the author of the question, just looked at your answer